# The State of Selected value keeps being reverted back to it's original value

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the value of selected to be of the changed one, but everytime I navigate to a different page then come back it keeps returning  `selected = true`
. I tried putting the `late bool selected;` then initializing in the initState() but it still doesn't work.

```
 bool selected = true;
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            var why = DateTime.parse(
                "${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)} ${widget.time}");
        
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFF9F9FB),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.time}",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 1,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("${widget.module}"),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_on,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 3,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "${widget.loc}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 13,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "${widget.lecturer}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 13,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(selected
                        ? Icons.notifications_none
                        : Icons.notifications_active),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // print(why);
                      print(widget.time);
                      print(widget.module);
                      print(widget.id);
        
                      setState(() {
                        selected = !selected; 
                      });
        
                      if (selected == false) {
                        displayNotification("${widget.module}", why, widget.id);
                      } else if (selected == true) {
                        localNotification.cancel(widget.id);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        
          Future<void> displayNotification(
              String lesson, DateTime lessonTime, int id) async {
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().zonedSchedule(
                id,
                lesson,
                "${lesson} ",
                tz.TZDateTime.from(lessonTime, tz.local),
                NotificationDetails(
                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                      "channel id", "channel name", "channel Description"),
                ),
                uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                    UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
                androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
          }
        }
        
        void initializeSetting() async {
          var initializeAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
          var initializeSetting = InitializationSettings(android: initializeAndroid);
          await localNotification.initialize(initializeSetting);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix :-

Just place your `selected` variable outside any class like this.

```
import ...//all the import statements
bool selected = true;

//Rest other code
```